# Change the value of HttpServletRequest#getRequestURI()

Tags: jsp

I want to edit the `HttpServletRequest#getRequestURI()` in my JSP scriplet code. Is there is any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reset some request URI value. But, you can write a request wrapper which will return the value you want.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I want to send the same request data to new URL

Comment: Can you elaborate what is that you are looking for.

Comment: Hi, I am using the richfaces fileupload control on my application .The problem  i am facing right now is that when i try to access my Application through CISCO SSL VPN the CISCO SSL VPN  changed the URL of all over the Application but when i try to upload the file to my backing bean  CISCO would not change the URL and request  was unable hit the server and my file was unable to upload.